# How can I install emmet plugin for NetBeans 12.2?

Tags: plugins, netbeans, emmet

i'm working in a web development proyect and put the html tags manually is a nightmare. I wanted to install emmet plugin in netbeans but i could't. When i watched videos about how to intall it, it seems like i have very few available plugins for netbeans and the emmet one is not included. Is there any way to install emmet plugin in my IDE? Why can i see very few plugins?

Comment: You can install the Emmet plugin for NetBeans 12.x by [downloading the plugin file org-lorenzos-emmet-1.4.0.nbm from GitHub](https://github.com/emmetio/netbeans/releases/tag/v1.4.0), then installing the plugin locally using **Tools > Plugins > Downloaded > Add Plugins...**. It appears to install OK; after NetBeans restarts there is a new menu entry **Edit > Emmet**.

Comment: Note, however, that NetBeans does not officially support the use of this plugin. That is why you can't find it using **Tools > Plugins > Available Plugins**. It has not been verified, and you should pursue any issues with the plugin author rather than the NetBeans team. [See here](https://github.com/emmetio/netbeans) for general information about using that Emmet plugin on NetBeans 12.x.

Comment: It worked, thx so much :)